# adb only show authorization for root - Android studio on Ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu

I recently switched to Ubuntu 15.10 (Gnome flavor). I installed Android Studio by copying it into /opt. From here I can start studio.sh as mentioned in the tutorial.

If I do this as root (sudo) I can see my Nexus 6P in the devices and an authorization pop-up is displayed on the device. If I do the same as a normal user I cannot do this. It's generally bad practice on Linux to constantly have root privileges so I really don't like this.

Is there a way I can fix this problem? Putting a flag on a file or adding a user to a group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the new update (Android Studio 2.0) I tried to fix the problem. Here is what I ended up doing:

Install the android-studio in /usr/local folder

```
mv android-studio /usr/local/android-studio
```

Change the ownership of the folder to the user you want and make sure that your user has the RW rights on that folder (recursively)

```
chown -R user:user /usr/local/android-studio
chmod -R u+rw /usr/local/android-studio
```

Android uses a key to enable the current user to connect to the device. By default, these files cannot be accessed by your own user (root is the owner) therefore you need to set the current user as the owner and, again, set correct usage rights.

```
sudo chown -R user:user .android
chmod -R u+rw .android
```

Lastly, sometimes it happens that the adb-tool has root as owner; you need to change that to your own user.

```
sudo chown -R user:user  ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
chmod -R u+rw ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

**NOTES:**

1. In this scenario I used the user privileges to ensure access. If multiple users will use the same installation you'll have to do the same but with group privileges. In general this is the way:

   sudo chown -R user:group  folder
   chmod -R g+rw folder
2. If you wan't to debug using adb in the command line you'll have to make sure that adb points to the correct installation folder (not the one from root; and not the one that is suggested when typing adb in the commandprompt)

   whereis adb
   // This should point to platform-tools folder of the current user

If this is not the case, you can change the PATH variable to point to the correct version of adb.

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

While installing Android Studio, copy it at a location like `/home/[user]/[some_folder]`

The `/opt` folder requires `sudo` privileges but if you will place it in any directory inside `/home/[user]/` you will not need that.

Comment: Thank you, I read online that this was the folder to install software in.

Comment: That's correct. Certain software are installed in this directory. But for android studio, you just need to run `studio.sh`. So, it doesn't matter where do you copy the files. Also, if this solved your problem, you can mark this answer as correct, to facilitate the future visitors.

Comment: Sadly I've tried this but it didn't work. I also tried applying chown -R user:user and chmod u+rwx to the folder. I did the same for the folder where the SDK is located.